# How to import a typescript class into other typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I know I'm making this more difficult than it should be.

Ionic 3/Angular. 
I have started to create a component and realized its not really that.  All the class does is do an ionic popup and if the user clicks yes call a services.

```
import { AlertController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WSService } from './ws.service';

export class confirmPopup {


  constructor(private wsService: WSService ,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private navCtrl: NavController) { }

showPopup(){

let popup = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: "Show Popup",
      message: "Are you okay today?",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            //Do nothing
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            this.wsService.register()
            .then( response => {

            this.navCtrl.setRoot(AnotherPage);
            })
          }
        }
      ]
    })

    popup .present();
}
```

Trying to use this class in two other components.

I import it and put it in the constructor, but I get the error "Can't resolve all parameters for..."

Not sure what other special thing Angular needs me to do, to get the class imported correctly?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#create-an-injectable-heroservice

Answer (score 0):

You have not decorated your class with `@Injectable()`decorator 
 When your service has its own dependencies you make use of this decorator to ensure that its dependencies are resolved first and then it is injected in other classes
The `@Injectable()` decorator identifies a service class that might require injected dependencies.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
    export class confirmPopup {


      constructor(private wsService: WSService ,
                  private alertCtrl: AlertController,
                  private navCtrl: NavController) { }

    .......
```

Comment: Hi if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.